# Assertion error 400 when testing a POST request from front end localhost to PostMan Proxy?

Tags: reactjs, http, post, postman

I am currenty programming a web/desktop client in react/node and I have to send table data that is currently populated with fictitious data to the backend and store it locally. I created the post request below attached to a button via a `<Button` using `onClick={sendTestData}`

this is my POST request currently:

```
function Tables() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const requestOptions = {
   method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ "name": "x" }),
  };

  const sendTestData = async () => {
    try {
      await fetch("http://localhost:8080/", requestOptions).then(
        response => {
          response.json();
        }
      )
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); }

  }
```

For some reason, if I were to run the proxy in postman on port 8080, and send a POST request through Postman to it I get the same error. Seems like my url is invalid no matter what I do and I am not exactly sure what it could be, thanks!

I have tried setting a proxy in package.json, i also tried sending POST requests directly from Postman to the proxy running on port 8080 and got error code 400 as well.